# Why token value is getting changed on Ethereum?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, ether, etherscan

I have created ERC20 token with 18 decimals. From web3 (application front end)  when I transfer 100 tokens, on etherscan it shows 0.0000000000000001 . When I call to get the balance then on UI it shows 100 tokens. How I can fix this?

**Method signature**:  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value)  public returns (bool) { }

The following is a **transaction link** for reference.

https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x7b50a2f1a013a0b15eb702f99d09d9a1c16a39bfa179329e246b6ba5b2318b12

Answer (score 0):

> When I call to get the balance then on UI it shows 100 tokens.

No, it shows you 100 base units of your token, and since your token decimal-resolution is 18, this is equivalent to 100 / 10 ^ 18 (0.0000000000000001) tokens.

---

In order to fix this in your web3-based application, replace `100` with `"100e18"`.

If you have `decimals` at hand, then you can also use:

```
`100e${decimals}`
```

---

More generally, you should:

- Take input `x` that you receive from the user, and pass to the contract function:

```
`${x}e+${decimals}`
```

- Take output `x` that you receive from the contract function, and pass to the user:

```
`${x}e-${decimals}`
```

Comment: Side note for future readers: Truffle 4.x, which relies on `BigNumber`, could handle stuff like `"100e18"`. Truffle 5.x, which relies on `BN`, cannot. Instead, you should do something like `new BN(100).mul(new BN(10).pow(new BN(18)))`, or simply `new BN(10).pow(new BN(20))`.